# 3D image display with different viewpoints

Tags: display

Is it possible show output 3D plots in a separate document (or iPad) to view an object all around made movable using mouse (or hand gesture) ?

Comment: Closest would be CDF player/wolfram alpha

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  Do you want to export Mathematica results into a file that preserves the 3-D structure and can be viewed by a separate piece of software?  If so, what piece of software do you want to use to view the generated file?  [Mathematica can export 3D data](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/3DGeometryAndModelingFormats.html) in a wide variety of formats.

Comment: For example in MS Word can we include a movable/viewpoint adjustable 3D image as a  3D object display and not just as a single projection,  *without* using any separate software? Just as a jpg image?

Comment: I would save a movie and embed that wherever you want. The play head can serve as the rotation control.

Answer (score 1):

If your graphics are not too complex, we can deploy them to the cloud and get an interactive, rotatable object.  Try this:

```
CloudDeploy[
 Plot3D[Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
]
```

You'll get an URL.  Click it, then when the page loads, click the graphics first, then drag to rotate.

---

A long-long time ago, there was [LiveGraphics3D](http://wwwvis.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/~kraus/LiveGraphics3D/).  This is a Java applet that could be run in the browser, and was made specifically for rotating Mathematica graphics.  At that time Mathematica didn't have this capability at all.

It's not fully compatible with Mathematica 6 and later, but it's an interesting piece of history.

---

Then there is another similar Java-based program called [JavaView](http://www.javaview.de/download/index.html). It can run either the browser as a Java applet, or as a standalone program.  It interfaces directly with Mathematica.  It supports Mathematica 10.

The big problem is that it is Java based and Java in the browser is already one step out the door.

---